# Not receiving packet in my packet listener

Tags: android, asmack

We are using asmack (Currently at version 4.0.3). I'm stuck with that version until February. First question on SO and new to smack, so please bear with me.
I'm receiving this packet with smack on Android (Showing in the debug log).

RCV (1):

```
< presence xmlns="jabber:client"
from="roomID@chat.myUrl.com/d67d0529-cdb3-4842-872b-8968ad635194" to="moo@myUrl.com/d67d0529-cdb3-4842-872b-8968ad635194">
< x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user">
< item affiliation="member"
 role="participant"
 name="my name"
 type="web"
 mute="false">
< /item>
< status xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc" code="301"></status>
< status xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc" code="110">< /status>
< /x>
< /presence>
```

My packet Filter

```
   PacketFilter presenceFilter = new AndFilter(new FromMatchesFilter(roomId + "@chat." + myUrl, true), new PacketTypeFilter(Presence.class));

    connectionXmpp.addPacketListener(myPacketListener, presenceFilter);
```

My packet Listener

```
 private class myPacketListener implements PacketListener{
        @Override
        public void processPacket(Packet packet) throws NotConnectedException {
        Log.i(TAG," Packet to xml : "+packet.toXML());
    }
}
```

How do I process that xml with all its content ? I receive two status codes, I need to parse them both. How do I process all data in the "x" tag. My packet listener returns a bunch of output, but nothing containing the status code 301 or the mute property.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below code in `processPacket` method to get `packet` details.

```
 @Override
    public void processPacket(Packet packet) throws NotConnectedException   
 {
    Log.i(TAG," Packet to xml : "+packet.toXML());
   //new code start
       Message message = (Message) packet;

            if (message.getType() == Message.Type.error) {
                return;
            }
            if (message.getBody() != null) {
 Log.i("Message==>",message.getBody());
 Log.i("Message From",message.getFrom())
            }
   //new code end
}
```